# react-transition-group card flip animation

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations, react-transition-group

I'm pretty new to react-transition-group and I'm trying to build a card flipping animation. I'm able to get the first side to flip but it doesn't like the idea of staying put onto the back side. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

```
import {useState} from "react";
import {CSSTransition} from "react-transition-group";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [flipped, setFlipped] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="card-container">
      <button
        className="card-button"
        onClick={() => setFlipped(!flipped)}
      >
        <CSSTransition
          in={flipped}
          timeout={1000}
          classNames="front-face-transition"
        >
          <div className="card-front">
            <p>front-side</p>
          </div>
        </CSSTransition>
        <CSSTransition
          in={!flipped}
          timeout={1000}
          classNames="back-face-transition"
        >
          <div className="card-back">
            <p>back-side</p>
          </div>
        </CSSTransition>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.card-container {
    width: 250px;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.card-container .card-button {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.front-face-transition-enter {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1000ms ease;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.front-face-transition-enter-active {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.front-face-transition-enter-done {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.back-face-transition-enter {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1000ms ease;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    display: block;
}
.back-face-transition-enter-active {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    display: block;
}
.back-face-transition-enter-done {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}


.card-front {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Also, here's a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-moore-c73ic?file=/src/App.js) link to this code in case that helps as well.

Comment: Well the linked project doesn't work at all for me. Is it supposed to flip when I click on it?

Comment: Sorry about that, not sure why the link is not working. Yes, the overall result should be a card flip along the y axis revealing the back-side of the card.

Comment: The link worked - the code didn’t. The card does not flip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot to unpack here.  There was no one error causing you issues, but a lot of little errors.  I will try to address them as best I can.  For the most part, your React is spot on, but the CSS is where you got into trouble.

tl;dr:  here is a working [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-architecture-gn5l1z)

1. You need to place transitions on the `active` class. This is by convention, but with your particular example, they could be permanent properties on the card elements.
2. The transform-style preserve 3d needs to be on the parent of the 3d element
3. If you want the front to be facing on page load, then your `flipped` logic is backwards
4. You had `display: none` on the front face, meaning it wasn't visible at all.
5. You need to specify an `exit-done` and a `enter-done` if you expect the transform to stay (the 180deg turn).  Set those rules to have the same transform value as the `active` class, that will keep the side "staying put" after the animation.
6. Back face visibility can be a permanent property on the face elements
7. Display block on the back face was doing nothing--it was already block as it is a div element. I think you meant to put it on the card-front rules.
8. Need to set a `perspective` property on the parent element to see any real 3d effect.  This is a pixel value that represents how far away the viewer is from the element in z space.
9. Some more tweaks to the card layout are necessary to get it right. I've added my basic stylings below.
10. The background of the container of the 3d elements (the button in your case) should have a background of `transparent`, otherwise the card will cut through the background when moving in 3d space.
11. It's a good idea to set an explicit background on the elements that rotating in this way, so there is a smoother animation.

I think that's everything.

##### Code

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [flipped, setFlipped] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="card-container">
      <button className="card-button" onClick={() => setFlipped(!flipped)}>
        <CSSTransition
          in={!flipped}
          timeout={1000}
          classNames="front-face-transition"
        >
          <div className="card-front">
            <p>front-side</p>
          </div>
        </CSSTransition>
        <CSSTransition
          in={flipped}
          timeout={1000}
          classNames="back-face-transition"
        >
          <div className="card-back">
            <p>back-side</p>
          </div>
        </CSSTransition>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
body {
  background-color: darkgray;
}

.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.card-container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.card-container .card-button {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 5000px;
}

.card-front,
.card-back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.card-front {
  background: beige;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.card-back {
  background: aliceblue;
}

.front-face-transition-enter {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.front-face-transition-enter-active {
  transition: all 1000ms ease;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.front-face-transition-enter-done {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.front-face-transition-exit {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.front-face-transition-exit-active {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition: all 1000ms ease;
}

.front-face-transition-exit-done {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.back-face-transition-enter {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.back-face-transition-enter-active {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transition: all 1000ms ease;
}
.back-face-transition-enter-done {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.back-face-transition-exit {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.back-face-transition-exit-active {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transition: all 1000ms ease;
}

.back-face-transition-exit-done {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

In general your code could be a lot DRYer.  Look for shared styles of similar elements and group them together to avoid unnecessary cruft. I left a few ways to optimize in my code example, but for example you can see that `.front-face-transition-exit-done` and `.front-face-transition-enter` have the same rules, put them together!

Good luck with CSSTransitions, and let me know if you have any questions.